# Istio on GKE - Admission webhook not working to inject sidecar-porxy

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have been trying to set up Istio on my existing GKE cluster.

I hev followed the steps mentioned on the Istio website for the installation - prerequisite.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/gke/

I have a private cluster so I added the firewall rule mention in the prerequisite.

```
gke-aiq-kubernetes-0a227ee8-all               default  INGRESS    1000      tcp,udp,icmp,esp,ah,sctp            False
gke-aiq-kubernetes-0a227ee8-master            default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:10250,tcp:443,tcp:15017         False
gke-aiq-kubernetes-0a227ee8-vms               default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:1-65535,udp:1-65535,icmp        False
```

and then install the istio with the demo profile.

```
istioctl install --set profile=demo
```

and then verify the intallation

```
istioctl verify-install
```

Which says everything is succeeded.

I labeled by namecpace "instio-inject=enabled" so that I will automatically get the sidecar porxy injected.

But when I trying to deploy something in the namespace I am getting following error:

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "pod-pending.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: context deadline exceeded
```

What I understand from this is that there is some connectivity issue, but I am not sure how to debug this.

I tried the debugging page from istio:

https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Troubleshooting-Istio#diagnostics

and after running the command:

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/services/https:istiod:https-webhook/proxy/inject -v4
```

I am conformend that this is connectivity issue:

```
t -v5
I1113 23:20:11.241079   40356 helpers.go:199] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server is currently unable to handle the request",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "details": {
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "UnexpectedServerResponse",
        "message": "Error trying to reach service: 'dial tcp 10.48.3.25:15017: i/o timeout'"
      }
    ]
  },
  "code": 503
}]
F1113 23:20:11.241367   40356 helpers.go:114] Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

Need help, I am new to GKE.

Answer (score 7):

I figured out the issue.

I have 7 different GCP projects configured with my gcloud profile and I was in a different project while running the gcloud command. (all gke clusters have the same name)

**Steps from the command line:**

I logged in to the GCP UI from the browser search the firewall under VPC and opened the ports manually there and it worked.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list --filter="name~gke-<clustername>-[0-9a-z]*-master"
```

Then get the firewall rule name.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules update <firewall rule name> --allow tcp:10250,tcp:443,tcp:15017
```

The idea here is to add the **tcp:15017** which is required by the admission hook.